# I converted my script sh to bash and I got SIGINT problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In my script I changed the shebang `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`. And my script has the following lines:

```
ctrlc(){
    echo; kill -INT 0; exit 0
}
trap ctrlc 2
```

In `bash` when I pressed `^C` it was all ok, the program exits normally. But in `sh` the program still exits, but I got this message:
`/mnt/c/Users/user/Documents: 1: Maximum function recursion depth (1000) reached`
Why am I getting this and is there a way to not to seeing it? Thank you.

Comment: put a `trap - INT; ` in your `ctrlc` function before the `kill` command.

Comment: Thanks it worked! But how it worked, different from bash?

Comment: Also I got the same problem with ```^D```. In bash, I solved it with adding the code ```|| kill -INT 0``` after every ```read```. For example; ```read -p "[y/n] " answer || kill -INT 0```But I don't know how to do it in ```sh```?

Comment: `trap - INT` has reset the signal handler for `SIGINT` from your handler to the default (ie terminate), preventing your script from re-entering the trap in an infinite loop. I don't think that the `bash`'s behaviour is standard.

Comment: Using that `kill -INT 0` so liberally doesn't sound like a good idea -- if your script is called from another script (or non-interactive daemon, etc) both will run in the same process group and `kill -INT 0` will kill both.

Comment: I see. So what it means ```Maximum function recursion depth (1000) reached```exactly?

Comment: That your shell decided to cut short the recursion at some limit instead of going on and crashing with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this

```
 trap 'echo " "; echo "PROGRAM INTERRUPTED"; echo " "; exit 1' INT
```

Comment: They could, but could you explain why they should?